# Changing from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net 4.0 causing web services to fail

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-6

This is an existing asp.net application (VS 2008) which makes calls to web services. Everything was working fine. Recently, the IIS (ver 6) was changed to use ASP.net 4.0(from asp.net 2.0) and all the web service calls are failing now.

The error in the application log states 'Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid'

I am new to this application and just dont know how to fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so your application is a .net 2.0 application, and you changed the site version to .net 4?  Why was your website upgraded to .Net 4?  Either upgrade your application to .Net 4, or downgrade your site to .Net 2.  You can't have them mismatching.

Comment: The web site was upgraded to .net 4 to fix other major issues. The application that I am trying to fix is a windows application. How do I upgrade it to .net 4. Also do I need to update the windows services too?

Comment: the application that is the problem is the windows services that you have.  You can't just have windows services working on an IIS server, and then change the sites .Net version without changing the services.  That will definitely break it.  You need to get a hold of the web services code, go to the project's properties, and change it's version to .Net 4 instead of .net 2.  Your windows services should be fine, since they aren't using IIS (theoretically).

Comment: Thanks! I built all the Web Services in VS 2010 with .net 4.0 and updated the web references in the web application and it woks now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something? Have a look at [here](http://www.aspnettricks.com/archives/forms-authentication-failed-for-the-request-reason-the-ticket-supplied-was-invalid/). Apparently it's to do with IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You will have to upgrade your application too. Basically, you need to change your reference from .net 2.0 to the net 4 dll's.